# C++ Template Metaprogramming and Call By Need Evaluation

Tags: c++, templates, meta-programming

I recently wrote a fairly complex C++ meta function that boils down to:

```
template <size_t N, typename val>
struct Rec {
    using type = typename std::conditional<N == 0,
        val,
        typename Rec<N - 1, val>::type>::type;
};
```

Both Clang and G++ barf on this type of recession, stating that, "Template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of X". I quickly rewrote the program and fixed the problem, but it got me thinking about the evaluation strategy of C++ template parameters.

Is there anything in the C++ standard that would prevent templates from using call by need evaluation of template parameters, or is this limitation purely an implementation defect?

Comment: @ChrisF it turns out Bart van Ingen Schenau has written an answer that explains OP's question - what is the compiler's "need" that triggers the infinite loop even though the compiler already adopts a "call by need evaluation" strategy. In contrast, a layman's response would just be "don't do that, do this instead", which would get the work done but the question unanswered. I think P.SE is a suitable place for fostering this type of questions, for a grace period, after which it might have to be cleaned up if nobody answered.

Comment: @rwong - Yeah - I had to close the question as something so I could reopen, but then forgot to clean up after myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To instantiate `std::conditional<N==0, val, typename Rec<N-1, val>::type>`, the compiler needs to prove that both `val` and `Rec<N-1, val>::type` evaluate to a type and that `N==0` evaluates to a constant expression that can be used in a boolean context.
If those conditions are not met, then the program is not well-formed and requires a diagnostic.

It is also only after evaluating the template arguments that the compiler can start looking for specializations that match, because for all the compiler knows, there might be a specialization of `std::conditional` for the parameters `true`,`val`,`Rec<-1,val>::type` that is more specialized than the default one for `std::conditional<true, T, F>`.
This is also why you need a specialization of `Rec` to stop the recursion: The condition used in `std::conditional` is only checked *after* the recursion has run its course and hit a terminating condition.

The compiler would be perfectly happy if you added the specialization

```
template <class val>
class Rec<-42, val> {
  typedef void type;
};
```

and give you the expected results (even if val != void).